# numpy advanced indexing on multidimensional-array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Say `x` is a 3x3 numpy array that contains the following:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
              [ 4.,  5.,  6.],
              [ 7.,  8.,  9.]])
```

is there some indexing that can give me the following subarray:

```
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 5.,  6.]])
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes things like `x[(0,2), 0:2]`  but to no avail. I could not get subsets like the one i mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [integer array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) with a tuple of arrays:

```
>>> rows = np.array([[0, 0],
...                  [1, 1]], dtype=np.intp)
>>> columns = np.array([[0, 1],
...                     [1, 2]], dtype=np.intp)
>>> x[rows, columns]
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 5.,  6.]])
```

Comment: Thanks, actually based on your suggestion the following also seems to work (I'm looking for a one-liner):  
`x[[[0, 0],[1, 1]], [[0, 1],[1, 2]]]`

Comment: okay, I wasn't aware you were looking for short code so I chose to show the explicit one. It is a bit clearer what the rows represents and what the columns are. :)

Answer (score -3):

you can use

```
x[:2,:2]
```

to solve your problem